# Error When Editing ImageList in Multi-Language Form

Tags: c#, forms, multilingual, imagelist, resource-files

I just experienced an error and found [another person reporting the error](https://goo.gl/CDokKM) - with no solution - in 2008.  I thought I would post it here, too, in hopes it has been resolved in the last 7 years.

In C#, in Visual Studio 2013, when you edit an ImageList in a form's designer, the binary data gets stored in an ImageStream in the form's default resource file <form_name>.resx.  If you look at the designer of this resource file, under 'Other', you will see a row for <ImageList_name>.ImageStream.  You can look at the code of this resource file and see an XML item for `<data name="<ImageList_name>.ImageStream"...` in which the `<value>` tag contains the binary data for the images in the list.

The problem is that when you edit this list, for example adding an image to the list, the default resource file's image stream data changes, but any other languages' resource file's image stream data is not updated.  So when you run your application with the language set to match one of those other resource files (such as <form_name>.ru.resx for Russian), when the form is initializing you will get an exception when something like this runs:

```
this.<ImageList_name>.Images.SetKeyName(20, "");
```

Here I've added a 21st image, but when this line runs against the Russian resource file, there is only binary data for 20 images, so an exception is thrown.

I have worked around this problem by deleting the ImageStream definition from all the multi-language resource files.  This guarantees that the ImageStream gets pulled from the default resource file instead.

I would like to know if there is a way to propagate changes made to a resource file to the other languages' files.  I have the same general desire when it comes to strings, as I'd like to be able to add a new string to the default file and have that string be added to the other languages' files as well, with some default "fill in the translation later" value.  Barring that, is there a more elegant solution to this problem than the one I've used?

Thanks,

Dan